# Kernel Estimation

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am working on a project in which I am given with a filter `K`. I need to:

> Find a matrix A such that each row of matrix A is the concatenation of
>   pixels corresponding to the filter K.

```
K = [ k11 k12 k13 
      k21 k22 k23 
      k31 k32 k33]
```

I am unable to find `A`. I am using MATLAB.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please include your source code inside your question.

Comment: The problem is that I don't understand what does "each row of matrix A is the concatenation of pixels corresponding to the filter K" mean. This is what is written in the paper I am trying to implement. I'll write the code once I get to know this.
Could you please help me understanding this?

Comment: My guess is that concatenation is simply a strangely chosen term here. Probably the author wants to say the weighted mean according to filter `K`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are talking about pixels, I assume you want to do two dimensinal kernel smoothing.

As `K` is a 3x3 matrix I suspect that to determine given an input matrix `Image` you can find a certain point of A in the following way:

```
for i = 2:size(Image,1)-1
    for j = 2:size(Image,2) -1
        A(i,j) = sum(sum( Image(i-1:i+1,j-1:j+1) .* K ))
    end
end
```

Of course you will still need to choose how to deal with the edges/corner cases, but I will leave that to you.